# How to get a section inside other sections in config minecraft=

Tags: java, minecraft

How can I take sections from another section? For example, I would like to take the "repair-cost" sections. I tried

```
Main.getConfiguration().getConfigurationSection("repair.items.SWORD:CUTLASS.repair-cost").getKeys(false)
```

but return null

```
repair:
  gui:
    test: "test"
  confirm:
    test: "test"  
  items: 
    "SWORD:CUTLASS":
      melt:
        - "test"
      repair-cost:
        "1-100":
          - "diamond 64"
        "101-200":
          - "diamond 128"
```

This is the error, line 60 is the `Main.getConfiguration()`:

```
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'armaiolo:riparaoggetti' in plugin Armaiolo v1.0
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47)
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:159)
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:826)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:2267)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnection.c(PlayerConnection.java:2082)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:2035)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:50)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:8)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$ensureMainThread$1(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:55)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:136)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:109)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.bb(MinecraftServer.java:1325)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:1318)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:119)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:1294)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1138)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:292)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at it.endlessgames.armaiolo.commands.fabbro.onCommandRepair(fabbro.java:60)
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: For me it works. Are you sure it's in the config ? there isn't error ?

Comment: Yes, it's in the config. It gives a NullPointerException

Comment: What is null exactly ? Can you print each variable ? `Main.getConfiguration()` then `config.getConfigurationSection()` ...

Comment: The getConfigurationSection returns null, the config works.

Comment: Have you checked if `Main.getConfiguration()` doesn't return another section ? Also, the config that you show doesn't have parent section ? For me it's only one of them, because I run it in local and it works.

Comment: Do you have news about this ?